# sql IN reverse usage

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to show products belongs to that location but I failed.

**db_products.locationId** stores id's string like **1,2,5,9**

**:locationId** stores location id like **5** I send this variable as parameter to sql query.

```
    SELECT db_products.*, 
           db_assets.path 
      FROM db_products INNER JOIN 
           db_assets ON db_assets.guid = db_products.guid 
     WHERE db_products.pcId = 1 AND 
           :locationId IN (db_products.locationId) 
  ORDER BY db_products.id
```

Comment: It is not legal syntax to attempt to create a parameterised bound column name!

Comment: Typo? it seems that you've omitted `AND` after `db_products.pcId = 1`

Comment: THis MUST be generating an ERROR message, did you look at it?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko fixed ty

Comment: You cannot parameterise and bind column names like this `:locationId IN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your data structure!  Do not store integers as strings in a list.  Why not?

- Integers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- SQL has poor string handling.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- The resulting queries cannot make use of indexes.
- SQL has a *great* data structure for storing lists.  It is called "table".

So, use a junction table.  You can look it up.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In this case, MySQL has `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT p.*, a.path 
FROM db_products p INNER JOIN 
     db_assets a
     ON a.guid = p.guid 
WHERE p.pcId = 1  AND
      FIND_IN_SET(:locationId, p.locationId) > 0
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: you are absolutely right but I have to do this :( your answer works. thank you so much